# iPhone is there a scroll to toggle fullscreen control like Google+ app?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitoolbar

I'm thinking of ways to offer the users of my app an immersive fullscreen experience, while still offering an ability to view tools/controls. It appears that Google + app has a good model for dealing with fullscreen view mode:

The latest Google+ app for iPhone implements a control with the following behavior:

- when the user browsing the circle articles,
- **Swipe down** to gradually hide navbar and bottom toolbar.
- **Swipe up** to gradually reveal toolbar
  and navbar.

Upon initial examination, it appeared to me that I can increase view frame's height in response to touchesMoved or viewDidScroll. The inner container would resize itself, while the bars would be pushed offscreen.

**To avoid reinventing the wheel, is there some open source view I can use to try out 
"swipe down for fullscreen" behavior in my own app?**

Here's the bar that gets pushed offscreen:

[image: Google + toolbar]